# Give access to Django Admin (staff status) by adding to Group

Tags: django, django-admin

To give a user the ability to login to the Django Admin, we set their `staff` flag.

Is there a way to make a "staff" `Group` where everyone put into it gains access to the admin page without manually setting staff status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [Django Admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site) (follow the doc, it's pretty amazing).

During the time, create a custom admin site class and override it's **`has_permission(...)`** method

```
from django.contrib import admin


class MyCustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):

    def has_permission(self, request):
        has_perm = super().has_permission(request)
        if has_perm:
            return True
        return request.user.groups.filter(name="YourGroupName").exists()
```